# convert file to uInt8Array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload, uint8array

I want to upload files from angular to postgresql using golang api.

In the angular part, I want to convert my `file` to `uInt8Array`. I have converted the array, but it is inside something I don't know of (as shown in the image)

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S90dh.png)

So how can I get the uInt8Array inside a variable like `let x : uInt8Array = y;`

Here is how far I tried.

**x.component.html**

```
<input (change)="onFileSelected($event)" type="file" id="fileUpload">
```

**x.component.ts**

```
onFileSelected(event) {
 console.log("called");
 const file: File = event.target.files[0];
 if (file) {
   console.log(file.arrayBuffer());
   console.log("call finished");
 }
}
```

Output was in previous screenshot.

Comment: Code should be posted **here**.

Comment: @Pointy where??

Comment: StackOveerflow has facilities like Codepen etc, there's no reason to post a link to an image.

Comment: @Pointy, my level is low, can I do it too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just construct a Uint8Array from array buffer output

```
file.arrayBuffer().then(buff => {
    let x = new Uint8Array(buff); // x is your uInt8Array
    // perform all required operations with x here.
});
```

As per question it should be looking like this

```
onFileSelected(event) {
     console.log("called");
     const file: File = event.target.files[0];
     if (file) {
         file.arrayBuffer().then(buff => {
             let x = new Uint8Array(buff); // x is your uInt8Array
             // perform all required operations with x here.
             console.log(x);
         });
         console.log("call finished");
     }
}
```

Comment: now it becomes a Promise<Uint8Array> . how can I make promise of  Promise<Uint8Array> to Uint8Array? (can you update your code to show me that please?)

Comment: I think you're doing something like this `console.log(file.arrayBuffer().then(buff => new Uint8Array(buff)));` then you will have the promise output. But you should do the operations inside the promise then callback. Just take a look how promise works in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: ok i will look for it

Comment: also updated the answer that may help better.